# How to compute band structure from real space Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, simulations, tight-binding

I will often see a paper where someone has diagonalized a tight binding model in real space, see for example Eq 1 of https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2516-1075/ab9f94/pdf. Immediately afterwards, one often includes a band structure computed from the Hamiltonian.

My question is: how do I numerically go from a real space tight binding Hamiltonian, where every row/column corresponds to an atomic orbital, to computing band structures? It is clear how to do so when the Hamiltonian is expressed in a plane wave basis, because then $\vec{k}$ is just a parameter, but I am unsure how to go directly from a diagonalized TB hamiltonian to the band structure

Comment: Look at Chapters 1 & (subsequently) 5 of [ https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295 ] by Asboth et al.

Answer (score 2):

The tight-binding Hamiltonian for a system with periodic boundary conditions and $N$ unit cells in the direction of periodicity can in real space be written as the following $N\times N$ block matrix:
\begin{equation}
H = \begin{pmatrix}
A& B & & B^{\dagger}\\
B^{\dagger} & \ddots &\ddots &\\
  &\ddots &\ddots &B\\
B&&B^{\dagger}&A
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a Hermitian matrix. Now, one can see that a vector of the form
\begin{equation}
V = \begin{pmatrix}
v\\v\omega_j \\ v\omega_j^2 \\ \vdots \\ v\omega_j^{N-1}
\end{pmatrix}, 
\end{equation}
where $\omega_j = \frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}j}{N}$ and $v$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
(A+B\omega_j+B^{\dagger}\omega_j)v = \lambda v,
\end{equation}
is an eigenvector of $H$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Now, if we make the problem continuous/add infinitely many unit cells in the direction with periodic boundary conditions, we realize that we are interested in the eigenvalues of the matrices
\begin{equation}
H(k) = A+e^{ik}B+e^{-ik}B^{\dagger},
\end{equation}
with $k\in[0,2\pi]$
This is your Bloch Hamiltonian and it will give you the eigenvalues as a function of $k$, and thus the band structure. In the reference mentioned in the comment ([A Short Course on Topological Insulators: Band-structure topology and edge states in one and two dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295)), they do it explicitly for the SSH-chain.